# pymemcache does not support caching python objects

Tags: python, caching, serialization, memcached, numpy-ndarray

I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-memcached-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial to install and configure memcached service on server. Then I tried to interact with memcached through [pymemcached](https://github.com/pinterest/pymemcache) package.

I used this code as `process1.py`:

```
from time import sleep
from pymemcache.client.base import Client
from pymemcache import serde
import cv2
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


client = Client(('127.0.0.1', 11211),
                serializer=serde.python_memcache_serializer,
                deserializer=serde.python_memcache_deserializer)

# result = client.get('some_key')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video/vdo.mp4')

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    client.set("image", frame)
    print("cached")

    if not ret:
        break

    # cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

    # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
    # if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    #     break

    sleep(0.05)

cap.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this one as `process2.py`:

```
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import cv2
from flask import Flask, Response
# from process1 import client

from pymemcache.client.base import Client
from pymemcache import serde

app = Flask(__name__)


client = Client(('127.0.0.1', 11211),
                serializer=serde.python_memcache_serializer,
                deserializer=serde.python_memcache_deserializer)


def gen():
    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        img = np.asarray(client.get('image'), np.uint8)
        if img is not None:
            # img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
            frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()
            yield b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n'


@app.route('/')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


py_dir = "/home/masoud/anaconda3/envs/py37/bin/python"
process_dir = "/home/masoud/Desktop/PycharmProjects/share_memory_test"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = [py_dir, process_dir]
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8888, debug=True)
```

The weird thing is that I ran this code with no problem in my own laptop in ubuntu 18. but when I ran this on a server in my office (with ubuntu 16.04), I got this runtime error:

```
    File "codes/MSD/process1.py", line 139, in run
    client.set("stream_image_cached", a)
  File "anaconda3/envs/msd_ped_det/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymemcache/client/base.py", 
line 341, in set flags=flags)[key]
  File "anaconda3/envs/msd_ped_det/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymemcache/client/base.py", 
line 933, in _store_cmd self.sock.sendall(b''.join(cmds)) 

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I wonder where else I have to check to make it work!

Comment: Hi Masoud, any luck with this one? I am facing the same issue here.

Comment: @SandeepRajoria What object are you trying to cache? and can you use redis for caching instead of pymemcache?

Comment: @SandeepRajoria check this one. I used Redis instead of pymemcache. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747492/how-to-have-full-control-over-a-process-start-terminate-which-runs-in-parallel

Comment: Finally figured out --  
1. had to close() the connection in the __del__ function. 
2. added connect_timeout=5, timeout=30, no_delay=True options in the Client constructor. 
I guess it was mostly to do with the timeout though.