# how to have full control over a process (start/terminate) which runs in parallel with flask application?

Tags: python, opencv, flask, redis, video-streaming

This is my application architecture:

[image: architecture of my application]

In my code there is a `pedestrian.py` file which uses a while loop to read frames from rtsp link and after doing pedestrian detection process (available in this [link](https://github.com/masouduut94/deep_sort_pytorch)), it caches the frame in Redis.

(please note that in the loop each time the output frame is replaced with the previous output from loop. it means that there exists only one frame in redis in any moment.)

Then in flask application, I read processed frame from redis and send it for the clients.

This is the code for my pedestrian detection:

```
from redis import Redis
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import cv2
import torch
from os import environ


r = Redis('111.222.333.444')

class RealTimeTracking(object):
    """
    This class is built to get frame from rtsp link and continuously
    save each frame in the output directory. then we use flask to give it
    as service to client.
    Args:
        args: parse_args inputs
        cfg: deepsort dict and yolo-model cfg from server_cfg file

    """

    def __init__(self, cfg, args):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.cfg = cfg
        self.args = args
        use_cuda = self.args.use_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available()

        if not use_cuda:
            raise UserWarning("Running in cpu mode!")

        self.detector = build_detector(cfg, use_cuda=use_cuda)
        self.deepsort = build_tracker(cfg, use_cuda=use_cuda)
        self.class_names = self.detector.class_names

        self.vdo = cv2.VideoCapture(self.args.input)
        self.status, self.frame = None, None
        self.total_frames = int(cv2.VideoCapture.get(self.vdo, cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        self.im_width = int(self.vdo.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        self.im_height = int(self.vdo.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

        self.output_frame = None

        self.thread = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
        self.thread.submit(self.update)
        print('streaming started ...')

    def update(self):
        while True:
            if self.vdo.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.vdo.read()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                if self.status:
                    frame = self.frame.copy()
                    # frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
                    self.detection(frame=frame)
                    frame_to_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
                    r.set('frame', frame_to_bytes)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def detection(self, frame):
        im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # do detection
        bbox_xywh, cls_conf, cls_ids = self.detector(im)
        if bbox_xywh is not None:
            # select person class
            mask = cls_ids == 0

            bbox_xywh = bbox_xywh[mask]
            bbox_xywh[:, 3:] *= 1.2  # bbox dilation just in case bbox too small
            cls_conf = cls_conf[mask]

            # do tracking
            outputs = self.deepsort.update(bbox_xywh, cls_conf, im)

            # draw boxes for visualization
            if len(outputs) > 0:
                self.draw_boxes(img=frame, output=outputs)

    @staticmethod
    def draw_boxes(img, output, offset=(0, 0)):
        for i, box in enumerate(output):
            x1, y1, x2, y2, identity = [int(ii) for ii in box]
            x1 += offset[0]
            x2 += offset[0]
            y1 += offset[1]
            y2 += offset[1]

            # box text and bar
            color = compute_color_for_labels(identity)
            label = '{}{:d}'.format("", identity)
            t_size = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, 2)[0]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 3)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x1 + t_size[0] + 3, y1 + t_size[1] + 4), color, -1)
            cv2.putText(img, label, (x1, y1 + t_size[1] + 4), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, [255, 255, 255], 2)
        return img


if __name__ == "__main__":

    args = parse_args() # argument: --rtsp_link = 'rtsp://me@111.222.333.444/Channels/105'
    cfg = get_config()
    cfg.merge_from_dict(model)
    cfg.merge_from_dict(deep_sort_dict)
    vdo_trk = RealTimeTracking(cfg, args)
    vdo_trk.run()
```

This is the code for flask server `app.py`:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from time import sleep
from os import getenv
from os.path import join
import subprocess
from flask import Response, Flask

from config.config import DevelopmentConfig
from redis import Redis

r = Redis('111.222.333.444')
app = Flask(__name__)

def gen():
    while True:
        frame = r.get('frame')
        if frame is not None:
            yield b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n'

@app.route('/')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_dotenv()
    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)
    cmd = ['python', join("my_project.dir", "pedestrian.py"), '--rtsp_link=rtsp://me@111.222.333.444/Channels/105']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    sleep(6)
    app.run()
```

This code runs perfectly in my system.

As you can see I use the cmd command to run the pedestrian detection on rtsp link **before** running flask server.

But what I really need for this task is to be able to **switch between different cameras**. I mean while the flask server is running, I want to be able to terminate the `pedestrian.py` process in any moment the request comes and restart the `pedestrian.py` with new `--rtsp_link`argument (switch to another camera).

something like this:

```
@app.route('/cam1'):
    def cam1():
        stop('pedestrian.py')
        cmd = ['python', join("my_project.dir", "pedestrian.py"), '--rtsp_link=rtsp://me@111.222.333.444/Channels/101']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)

@app.route('/cam2'):
    def cam2():
        stop('pedestrian.py')
        cmd = ['python', join("my_project.dir", "pedestrian.py"), '--rtsp_link=rtsp://me@111.222.333.444/Channels/110']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

My flask knowledge might not be good enough. I probably need to use post method and also authentication for that.

Would you tell me how can I implement such thing in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to automate start/stop the pedestrian detection. more details available in [my repo](https://github.com/masouduut94/deep_sort_pytorch/blob/master/webserver/rtsp_webserver.py):

from os.path import join
    from os import getenv, environ
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    import argparse
    from threading import Thread

```
from redis import Redis
from flask import Response, Flask, jsonify, request, abort

from rtsp_threaded_tracker import RealTimeTracking
from server_cfg import model, deep_sort_dict
from config.config import DevelopmentConfig
from utils.parser import get_config

redis_cache = Redis('127.0.0.1')
app = Flask(__name__)
environ['in_progress'] = 'off'


def parse_args():
    """
    Parses the arguments
    Returns:
        argparse Namespace
    """
    assert 'project_root' in environ.keys()
    project_root = getenv('project_root')
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("--input",
                        type=str,
                        default=getenv('camera_stream'))

    parser.add_argument("--model",
                        type=str,
                        default=join(project_root,
                                     getenv('model_type')))

    parser.add_argument("--cpu",
                        dest="use_cuda",
                        action="store_false", default=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


def gen():
    """
    Returns: video frames from redis cache
    """
    while True:
        frame = redis_cache.get('frame')
        if frame is not None:
            yield b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n'


def pedestrian_tracking(cfg, args):
    """
    starts the pedestrian detection on rtsp link
    Args:
        cfg:
        args:
    Returns:
    """
    tracker = RealTimeTracking(cfg, args)
    tracker.run()


def trigger_process(cfg, args):
    """
    triggers pedestrian_tracking process on rtsp link using a thread
    Args:
        cfg:
        args:
    Returns:
    """
    try:
        t = Thread(target=pedestrian_tracking, args=(cfg, args))
        t.start()
        return jsonify({"message": "Pedestrian detection started successfully"})
    except Exception:
        return jsonify({'message': "Unexpected exception occured in process"})


@app.errorhandler(400)
def bad_argument(error):
    return jsonify({'message': error.description['message']})


# Routes
@app.route('/stream', methods=['GET'])
def stream():
    """
    Provides video frames on http link
    Returns:
    """
    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route("/run", methods=['GET'])
def process_manager():
    """
    request parameters:
    run (bool): 1  -> start the pedestrian tracking
                0  -> stop it
    camera_stream: str -> rtsp link to security camera
    :return:
    """
    # data = request.args
    data = request.args
    status = data['run']
    status = int(status) if status.isnumeric() else abort(400, {'message': f"bad argument for run {data['run']}"})
    if status == 1:
        # if pedestrian tracking is not running, start it off!
        try:
            if environ.get('in_progress', 'off') == 'off':
                global cfg, args
                vdo = data.get('camera_stream')
                if vdo is not None:
                    args.input = int(vdo)
                environ['in_progress'] = 'on'
                return trigger_process(cfg, args)
            elif environ.get('in_progress') == 'on':
                # if pedestrian tracking is running, don't start another one (we are short of gpu resources)
                return jsonify({"message": " Pedestrian detection is already in progress."})
        except Exception:
            environ['in_progress'] = 'off'
            return abort(503)
    elif status == 0:
        if environ.get('in_progress', 'off') == 'off':
            return jsonify({"message": "pedestrian detection is already terminated!"})
        else:
            environ['in_progress'] = 'off'
            return jsonify({"message": "Pedestrian detection terminated!"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_dotenv()
    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

    # BackProcess Initialization
    args = parse_args()
    cfg = get_config()
    cfg.merge_from_dict(model)
    cfg.merge_from_dict(deep_sort_dict)
    # Start the flask app
    app.run()
```